# Set Jquery slider value from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-slider

I have a Jquery range slider (two values). I am trying to set the value from JSON:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/SensorDatas/LoadSettings',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#sensor1slide").slider('option','values',0, result.sensor1min);
            $("#sensor1slide").slider('option','values',1, result.sensor1max);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.responseText); $("#loading").val("Error"); }
    })
```

My sliders are not being updated, even though I know the values are being returned. I was wondering if it was because they are not cast correctly?

When I analysis the browser console I get this error:

```
TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function
$("#sensor1slide").slider('option','values',0, result.sensor1min);
```

Comment: this error means that your plugin is not defined. Did you add a reference to the plugin files? did you check if they are loading?

Comment: @AwRak - they are loading and working. I am using their value in another widget, I just cannot seem to programmatically set the value

Comment: the way you wrote it you're getting the value,not setting it. Try
var min=result.sensor1min;var max=  result.sensor1max; $( "#sensor1slide" ).slider({values: [ min,max ]});